# Replace exponential values in a table by normal float values

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table in my html file:

```
<table class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th>timestamp</th>
      <th>cid1</th>
      <th>cid2</th>
      <th>cid3</th>
      <th>cid4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>2023-04-08 15:39:21</td>
      <td>1.0</td>
      <td>55.560000</td>
      <td>5.123143e+06</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2023-04-08 15:39:21</td>
      <td>1.0</td>
      <td>27913.540000</td>
      <td>4.653931e+04</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

As we can see there is many float values in cells with exponential form or with many zero in the end. Now I wrote a calc in a head of file:

```
<form onsubmit="return false;"oninput="document.getElementById('rez_float').innerHTML= 
parseFloat(document.getElementById('expo').value).toFixed(20).replace(/\.?0+$/,'')">
<input id="expo" value="Paste exponential" onfocus="if (this.value === 'Paste exponential') this.value=''">  
<br>float = <output id="rez_float"></output>
</form>
```

This calc return me `2572962000` if I put `2.572962e+09`.

But I want to find in the table all cells contained exponential values and replace it by normalize float values with function `toFixed(20).replace(/\.?0+$/,'')`. And may be remove excessed zeros for values like to `27913.540000`.

How to make it with JS? I'm pythonist and I have beginner JS level. Help me please!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [number formatter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat) instance from the `Intl` API.

In the example below, I've chosen some [constructor options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat#parameters) that seem appropriate to the details of your question as I interpret it — but be sure to explore what's available.

```js
const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat("en-US", {
  maximumFractionDigits: 20,
  notation: "standard",
  roundingMode: "expand",
  signDisplay: "auto",
  style: "decimal",
  useGrouping: false,
});

const formatNumberCell = (td) => {
  const formatted = formatter.format(Number(td.textContent.trim()));
  td.textContent = formatted;
};

document.querySelectorAll("table > tbody > tr > td:not(:nth-of-type(1))")
  .forEach(formatNumberCell);
```

```css
table {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td, th, tr {
  border: 1px solid hsla(0, 0%, 50%, 0.2);
  padding: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>timestamp</th>
      <th>cid1</th>
      <th>cid2</th>
      <th>cid3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>2023-04-08 15:39:21</td>
      <td>1.0</td>
      <td>55.560000</td>
      <td>5.123143e+06</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2023-04-08 15:39:21</td>
      <td>1.0</td>
      <td>27913.540000</td>
      <td>4.653931e+04</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2023-04-08 15:39:21</td>
      <td>-41</td>
      <td>-27913.540000</td>
      <td>4.653931e-04</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

And if you don't like the extra `formatter` variable in your scope, you can just create it in a closure — here's an example with the same outputs above and a few others that compare the default number serializations against the custom format:

```js
const formatNumber = (() => {
  const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat("en-US", {
    maximumFractionDigits: 20,
    notation: "standard",
    roundingMode: "expand",
    signDisplay: "auto",
    style: "decimal",
    useGrouping: false,
  });
  return formatter.format.bind(formatter);
})();

for (const nStr of [
  "1.0",
  "55.560000",
  "5.123143e+06",
  "1.0",
  "27913.540000",
  "4.653931e+04",
  "-41",
  "-27913.540000",
  "4.653931e-04",
  "1.234e40",
  "-1.234e40",
  "1.234e-40",
  "-1.234e-40",
]) console.log(`Input: ${nStr}\nDefault: ${String(Number(nStr))}\nCustom: ${formatNumber(Number(nStr))}`);
```

[Code in the TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiATgWwIZQHIFdkCMCmiMAvDABRkCUJAfDAN4BQMMoksCK6UhJMY+AO4wAkmCgAbAHTY8hAGJI0UMgCJ8YALQBVAMqqANA2YsYaAB4BLZDnmJUwKJfAARSwHNLUCAC4YAJgAGAxMWMBAodGcwP1VoVDAAE1RERMNQmAB6TJgAAW9NfHMAB3xHQsREJAyqrCTLMHcAWRBE-Fii4oS0kNMYCA8wNwhiiVQAT1jULCgQdL7ocYl2mFU24GtUCXnTLAh8AHFa4ob3Pzgt-d6YAF9KAG4TRHwoLEQweCVuQilOZSlcA1EmQ-t9EA9GHcqI9GJxyGxoPxdFAiCA4DAANomVQARikgR2qgArESpESAGyBKkE67EqQ4-wAZhxABZGfgANSBcmEvE07H+ADsAE4cYyySzqfyWKoWVJyUTGcLmZzAizCZoWTiNULReKiZLqYS5QqlSrNGreVImSz8JKNXibXbpatHYzbZqXapNG6PfaQgBdagIkDLKQSEDuMgAAzExRmfgAJPQwMjEDcADpDfAXLASKBJ+hp05kWQERBkVMoyiUTNgADCe1myELoMwOHLpY7hEraZrN2jEKAA)

Comment: It's a greate solution! Thank you! But all text values in other columns will be NaN. How to correct it?

Comment: I found solution, it's just change value of :nth-of-type()